# Is it possible to create apex in 30 trail version?

Tags: sandbox

Can someone please confirm if we can use Apex in the 30-day trial version of Salesforce as currently new apex class and trigger option is disabled in the sandbox(created from the trial version)and I am not able to find Author apex option in profile.

Please suggest if we can use apex in the trial version.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the version of your trial. Why not just use a Developer Edition if you're trying to write code?

Comment: Could you please tell me which version to select if we want to use Apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you sign up for an Enterprise Edition trial to get access to Apex code. You'll know you're in the right trial because your browser's tab will read "Salesforce - Enterprise Edition". If it says "Salesforce - Professional Edition", you're in the wrong trial. You can sign up for an Enterprise Edition org **[here](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales-ee.jsp)**. Note that the Developer Console and UI still won't let you create classes directly; you need to deploy metadata using the metadata API, such as a github Deploy to Salesforce button, or Force.com IDE, or DX, etc. This asynchronous mode of deployment is required because tests must be run to deploy code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but when I fill all the required details and hit the sign up button then instead of creating an account, the page reloads and nothing happens.

Comment: @gs650x Try using a different email address.